# PreferenceFragment getListView

Tags: java, android, preferencefragment

(Google Translate)
I have a custom PreferenceFragment with icon and ImageView. This screen controls the notification of my app. By clicking on the Item disable or enable the notification when you click on ImageView (soundIcon) constantly changing the type of notification (vibration, sound). But when i click on ImageView (soundIcon) I do not know how I can get Item position. Here is my code and screeshot:

**FragmentNotification class**

```
public class FragmentNotifications extends PreferenceFragment {

    CheckBoxPreference beforeInputTrafficLighter;
    CheckBoxPreference brakeTesting;
    CheckBoxPreference speedLimit;
    CheckBoxPreference passengerTrains;

    View v;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
        beforeInputTrafficLighter = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("BeforeInputTrafficLighter");
        brakeTesting = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("BrakeTesting");
        speedLimit = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("SpeedLimit");
        passengerTrains = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("PassengerTrains");

        final IconPreferenceScreen ipsBeforeInputTrafficLighter = (IconPreferenceScreen) findPreference("BeforeInputTrafficLighter");
        final IconPreferenceScreen ipsBrakeTesting = (IconPreferenceScreen) findPreference("BrakeTesting");
        final IconPreferenceScreen ipsSpeedLimit = (IconPreferenceScreen) findPreference("SpeedLimit");
        final IconPreferenceScreen ipsPassengerTrains = (IconPreferenceScreen) findPreference("PassengerTrains");
        final Drawable beforeInputTrafficLighterIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_traffic_light_teal_48dp);
        final Drawable beforeInputTrafficLighterIconGrey = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_traffic_light_grey_48dp);
        final Drawable brakeTestingIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_brake_testing_red_48dp);
        final Drawable brakeTestingIconGrey = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_brake_testing_grey_48dp);
        final Drawable speedLimitIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_speed_limit_blue_48dp);
        final Drawable speedLimitIconGrey = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_speed_limit_grey_48dp);
        final Drawable passengerTrainsIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_passenger_trains_purple_48dp);
        final Drawable passengerTrainsIconGrey = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_passenger_trains_grey_48dp);

        final boolean[] beforeInputTrafficLighterColor = {true};
        beforeInputTrafficLighterColor[0] = this.beforeInputTrafficLighter.isChecked();
        if(beforeInputTrafficLighterColor[0]){
            ipsBeforeInputTrafficLighter.setIcon(beforeInputTrafficLighterIcon);
        }else{
            ipsBeforeInputTrafficLighter.setIcon(beforeInputTrafficLighterIconGrey);
        }
        ipsBeforeInputTrafficLighter.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (beforeInputTrafficLighterColor[0]) {
                    ipsBeforeInputTrafficLighter.setIcon(beforeInputTrafficLighterIconGrey);
                } else {
                    ipsBeforeInputTrafficLighter.setIcon(beforeInputTrafficLighterIcon);
                }
                beforeInputTrafficLighterColor[0] = !beforeInputTrafficLighterColor[0];
                return false;
            }
        });

        final boolean[] brakeTestingColor = {true};
        brakeTestingColor[0] = this.brakeTesting.isChecked();
        if(brakeTestingColor[0]){
            ipsBrakeTesting.setIcon(brakeTestingIcon);
        }else{
            ipsBrakeTesting.setIcon(brakeTestingIconGrey);
        }
        ipsBrakeTesting.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (brakeTestingColor[0]) {
                    ipsBrakeTesting.setIcon(brakeTestingIconGrey);
                } else {
                    ipsBrakeTesting.setIcon(brakeTestingIcon);
                }
                brakeTestingColor[0] = !brakeTestingColor[0];
                return false;
            }
        });

        final boolean[] speedLimitColor = {true};
        speedLimitColor[0] = this.speedLimit.isChecked();
        if(speedLimitColor[0]){
            ipsSpeedLimit.setIcon(speedLimitIcon);
        }else{
            ipsSpeedLimit.setIcon(speedLimitIconGrey);
        }
        ipsSpeedLimit.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (speedLimitColor[0]) {
                    ipsSpeedLimit.setIcon(speedLimitIconGrey);
                } else {
                    ipsSpeedLimit.setIcon(speedLimitIcon);
                }
                speedLimitColor[0] = !speedLimitColor[0];
                return false;
            }
        });

        final boolean[] passengerTrainsColor = {true};
        passengerTrainsColor[0] = this.passengerTrains.isChecked();
        if(passengerTrainsColor[0]){
            ipsPassengerTrains.setIcon(passengerTrainsIcon);
        }else{
            ipsPassengerTrains.setIcon(passengerTrainsIconGrey);
        }
        ipsPassengerTrains.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (passengerTrainsColor[0]) {
                    ipsPassengerTrains.setIcon(passengerTrainsIconGrey);
                } else {
                    ipsPassengerTrains.setIcon(passengerTrainsIcon);
                }
                passengerTrainsColor[0] = !passengerTrainsColor[0];
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_icon, null);

//        final ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
//        if(lv != null){
//            lv.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
//                @Override
//                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
//                    Log.d("fg", "action is " + event.getAction());
//                    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
//                        Log.d("fg", "Pos " + lv.getSelectedItemPosition());
//                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position " + lv.getSelectedItemPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
//                    return false;
//                }
//            });
//            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//                    Log.d("fg", "lv item is clicked");
//                }
//            });
//
//        }else{
//            Log.d("fg", "lv is null");
//        }
//
//
//        Log.d("fg", "Listview = " + lv);

        return v;
    }
}
```

**IconPreferenceScreen class**

```
public class IconPreferenceScreen extends CheckBoxPreference {

    private Drawable mIcon;

    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public IconPreferenceScreen(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_icon);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IconPreferenceScreen, defStyle, 0);
        mIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.IconPreferenceScreen_myIcon);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

        return super.onCreateView(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view) {
        super.onBindView(view);
        //add icon
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        if (imageView != null && mIcon != null) {
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 150;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 150;
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
        }
        //add soundIcon
        LinearLayout iconpref = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.iconpref);
        final ImageView soundIcon = new ImageView(getContext());
        soundIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_sound_off_grey_48dp));
        soundIcon.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                125,
                125));
        iconpref.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        soundIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "naja", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (soundIcon.getAlpha() == 1f) {
                    soundIcon.setAlpha(0.4f);
                } else {
                    soundIcon.setAlpha(1f);
                }
            }
        });
        iconpref.addView(soundIcon);



    }

    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        if ((icon == null && mIcon != null) || (icon != null && !icon.equals(mIcon))) {
            mIcon = icon;
            notifyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Drawable getIcon() {
        return mIcon;
    }
}
```

**pref.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <comzaqxs.vk.com.appname.customViews.IconPreferenceScreen
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="BeforeInputTrafficLighter"
        android:summary="@string/settings_check_box_before_input_traffic_lighters_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_check_box_before_input_traffic_lighters"/>

    <comzaqxs.vk.com.appname.customViews.IconPreferenceScreen
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="BrakeTesting"
        android:summary="@string/settings_check_box_testing_breakers_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_check_box_testing_breakers"/>

    <comzaqxs.vk.com.appname.customViews.IconPreferenceScreen
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="SpeedLimit"
        android:summary="@string/settings_check_box_speed_limit_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_check_box_speed_limit"/>

    <comzaqxs.vk.com.appname.customViews.IconPreferenceScreen
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="PassengerTrains"
        android:summary="@string/settings_check_box_passenger_trains_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_check_box_passenger_trains"/>



</PreferenceScreen>
```

**preference_icon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/iconpref"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@id/android:list"
            android:alpha="1" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />
        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:maxLines="2" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have no need of position .You can simply match key of preference preference.getKey()